# Как раздать интернет с компьютера через роутер

Tags: сеть, роутер, подсети

Есть ноутбук, который подключен к точке доступа встроенным модулем вайфай. Есть роутер Huawei hg532. Как с помощью роутера, подключенным проводным соединением к ноутбуку настроить раздачу интернета? Получается цепочка должна выглядеть так: точка доступа вайфай - ноутбук - роутер huawei, разбающий интернет через точку доступа. Операционка ubuntu

Comment: стандартными средствами network-manager

Answer (score 0):

Нажимаем "Добавить" / "Add"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем Wi-Fi

[image: Выбираем "Wi-Fi"]

Выбираем "Mode" - Hotspote

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]